# CR-10 MAX - Marlin Firmware settings help

Tags: marlin, firmware, creality-cr-10

I’m trying to build firmware for the CR-10 MAX. The git has no `config` example for this machine. And this is the first time for me to look into the settings. I’m using the firmware from [Tiny Machines](https://github.com/InsanityAutomation/Marlin/tree/CrealityDwin_2.0).

I’ve done the following upgrades:

- Hero Me 5 fan ducts
- Converted it to a direct drive with stock parts.

The settings below are what I currently have selected:

```
#define MachineCR10Max
#define PLUS // Adds BLTouch, allmetal, bilinear (standard), lerdge, 93 e-steps/mm
#define HotendStock
#define DirectDrive // Any direct drive extruder, reduces filament change lengths
#define ABL_BLTOUCH
#define GraphicLCD
#define ABL_BI
#define MeshFine
```

And these are questions on, if they are ok.

```
Changing probe offset for Hero Me 5 kit (values from manual)
#define X_MIN_POS -47
#define Y_MIN_POS 2
.
**Should I select AC or DC for the CR-10 MAX?**
//#define BedAC // **I think it is AC what the MAX has?**
//#define BedDC 
.
I think I do not need:
//#define AddonFilSensor 
.
**Would I want/need this?**
//#define POWER_LOSS_RECOVERY
```

————————

Am I complete like this or am I missing settings??

Comment: Welcome to SE.3DP. The configuration changes you list are not a part of marlin, and are likely a part of the fork of it you are using. I would recommend getting a fresh release of marlin straight from [the Marlin github](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin) and following [their instructions](https://marlinfw.org/docs/basics/install_platformio_vscode.html)

Comment: I know this question is 5+ months old, but I just wanted to help anyone that might come across this randomly. The CR-10 Max uses a Meanwell RSP-750-24 power supply, which supplies the bed with 24v of DC power. So you'd uncomment BedDC in the Configuration.h